# AWS Amplify iOS: what is the most reliable way to find if a user is logged in

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplify-ios

Is it ok to check

```
Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser() != nil
```

or should the app maintain a state variable and set that from this listener?

```
   _ = Amplify.Hub.listen(to: .auth) { payload in
        switch payload.eventName {
        case HubPayload.EventName.Auth.signedIn:
            // Update UI
            ....
```

If it's the latter, is that suppose to work even if the user logged in during one of the previous sessions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After further research and from Discord discussions looks like this is the best approach:

```
Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser() != nil
```

Comment: Thanks for this Answer. It helped us save a lot of time and effort